# Displaying different page layouts for record types

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, record-type

I have 2 different record types for the Contact object and I would want to display a different layout for each of them.

I was wondering if there is an already integrated option to do so or do I have to construct a custom visualforce page for both of them?

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to use visualforce? or are you asking if there is a way to do it via the point and click page layouts, or if you would have to make two vf pages?

Comment: As my question states I am asking if there is already a way to do it without having to build extra visualforce pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is standard Salesforce functionality. You will want to create your multiple page layouts and then when you go to create your multiple record types you will be able to assign which record types use which layouts. I have added a few links for you to view that should help you get this set up.

[Salesforce Record Types and Page Layouts](https://www.shellblack.com/whiteboard/salesforce-record-types-and-page-layouts/)

[Assigning Page Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutassign.htm)

Comment: thanks @cmmoutes13 that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: No Problem @MarcZaharescu

Answer (score 0):

apex:detail
The standard detail page for a particular object, as defined by the associated page layout for the object in Setup. This component includes attributes for including or excluding the associated related lists, related list hover links, and title bar that appear in the standard Salesforce application interface

Doesn't this do the trick?

FYI: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the link doesn't seem to be working. Also I think you didn't understand my question. I am asking whether or not there already exists a way in salesforce to display custom information based on the record type without having to build any extra visual force pages?

Comment: works for me :-/